# Can someone tell me in order what's going on in Peterson's solution for critical section?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, semaphore, critical-section

I tried searching for the concept but everywhere I got just the pseudocode and there was no good explanation provided. Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: There is an explanation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm). Could you be more specific on what parts are unclear to make the question a little less broad?

Comment: On the part, which turn comes first and how, so as to enter the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

Peterson's is an altruistic solution for Process Syncing. I'll keep it simple and stick to the case when there are 2 processes (let's call them A and B) only.

---

What happens in this case is that when process A wants to enter critical section, it sets its own flag to `true` (this indicates that A wants to enter the critical section) but tries to let B go in first by setting the turn to B.

Then, by means of a `while ( flag[B] && turn == B);` it puts itself on hold if B had set its flag to `true` as well. So you see that when A wanted to enter the critical section, it first tested whether B wanted to go in too and A put itself on hold if B wanted to go in.

---

This same would happen from B's side too.

---

So, if A and B both decided to enter the critical section simultaneously, then the one who last sets the turn would wait. This implies that if B sets `turn = A` in the end, then B will wait in its while loop - `while ( flag[A] && turn == A);`, A will finish processing the critical section and then unset `flag[A]`, breaking B's while loop and then B will enter the critical section itself.

---

I guess you will be able to understand the syncing steps of each process with the code below now. Following is the code for Process-i:

```
while (true) {
    flag[i] = TRUE; // indicating that process-i wants to enter the critical section
    turn = j;
    // Following WHILE starts and ends in one line. It's called busy-waiting.
    while ( flag[j] && turn == j); 

        FINISH THE CRITICAL SECTION

    flag[i] = FALSE; // process-i indicating that it is done now

        FINISH THE REMAINDER SECTION
}
```